# Relative entropy equality for a sequence of Bernoulli random variables

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, probability-distributions, entropy

We are given two joint probability distributions, $p$ and $q$, of $n$ Bernoulli random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$.

We denote by $p(x_k\mid x^{k-1})$ the probability $\mathbb{P}_p(X_k=x_k\mid X_1=x_1,\ldots, X_{k-1}=x_{k-1})$ and by $q(x_k\mid x^{k-1})$ the probability $\mathbb{P}_q(X_k=x_k\mid X_1=x_1,\ldots, X_{k-1}=x_{k-1})$, where the $\mathbb{P}$ subscript indicates which probability mass function we are referring to. For any integer $1\le m\le n$, $x^{m}$ denotes therefore the realization $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{m}$ of $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_{m}$.

---

**Question:** How can we prove that

$$D(p\parallel q)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}\sum_{x^{k-1}\in\{0,1\}^{k-1}}D\left(p\left(x_k\mid x^{k-1}\right)\parallel q\left(x_k\mid x^{k-1} \right) \right)\,,$$

where $D(p\parallel q):=\sum_{x^n\in\{0,1\}^n} \left(p(x^n)\log\left(\frac{p(x^n)}{q(x^n)}\right)\right)$ is the Kullback–Leibler divergence between $p$ and $q$?

---

---

***Note:*** *I tried to use the chain rule for the Kullback–Leibler divergence, but without success until now. Am I missing something trivial?*

Comment: The symbol coded by `\|`, used in $D(p\| q),$ does not have the horizontal spacing appropriate to a binary relation symbol. I changed to to `\parallel`, so now you see $D(p\parallel q). \qquad$

Comment: Thank you @MichaelHardy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This equality does not hold in general. E.g., suppose that $n=2$,
$$\big(P_p(X_1=i,X_2=j)\colon\; i=0,1,\,j=0,1\big)=
\frac1{30}\,\begin{pmatrix}
 4 & 9 \\
 9 & 8 \\
\end{pmatrix},$$
and
$$\big(P_q(X_1=i,X_2=j)\colon\; i=0,1,\,j=0,1\big)=
\frac1{17}\,\begin{pmatrix}
 2 & 6 \\
 2 & 7 \\
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Then the left- and right-hand sides of your conjectured equality are $0.132\ldots$ and $0.118\ldots$, respectively (assuming $\log=\ln$).

---

Here are the calculations, done in Mathematica:

[image]

Comment: @PenelopeBenenati : I don't see a reason for the equality to hold on (say) any neighborhood of any pair $(p,q)$. So, I selected $p$ and $q$ pretty much at random. Using the Mathematica code above, you can try $n=2$ in the case of interest, and I will be greatly surprised if the equality then holds -- sorry for having to say this.

Comment: If $\mathbb{P}_p(X_i=1)=\tfrac12$ for all $1\le i\le n$, i.e., '{p[0,0],p[0,1],p[1,0],p[1,1]}={1/4,1/4,1/4,1/4};' the equality seems correct using your code. The chain rule states that  $$D(p(X_1,X_2)\parallel q(X_1,X_2)))=D(p(X_1)\parallel q(X_1))+D(p(X_2|X_1)\parallel q(X_2|X_1))\,,$$ where $$D(p(X_2|X_1)\parallel q(X_2|X_1))=\sum_{x_1\in\{0,1\}} p(x_1)\sum_{x_2\in\{0,1\}}p(x_2|x_1)\log\left(\frac{p(x_2|x_1)}{q(x_2|x_1)}\right)\,.$$ If $p(x_i)=\tfrac12$ for all $i$, then we can replace $\sum_{x_1\in\{0,1\}} p(x_1)$ by $\tfrac12$ in the above sum. It is easy to extend this result for $n>2$.

Comment: @PenelopeBenenati : Yes, I think the equality is true when the $X_i$ are $p$-independent with $P_p(X_i)=1/2$ for all $i$. But this does not contradict my previous comment.

Comment: Yes, it's not a contradiction. I was trying to understand why in the specific problem I am working on the result seemed to hold. Thank you also for the Mathematica code, it was useful to understand the problem more deeply! (I suspect the above condition about $P_p(X_i)$ is not just sufficient, but also necessary).

Comment: @PenelopeBenenati : "not just sufficient, but also necessary" -- I guess so too.